# Using python to print (non-default networked printer)

Tags: python, winapi, printing

I have some code to generate a label for a networked label printer:

```
import win32ui
dc = win32ui.CreateDC()
dc.CreatePrinterDC()
dc.StartDoc('Label Document')
dc.StartPage()
fontdata = {'height':80}
font = win32ui.CreateFont(fontdata)
dc.SelectObject(font)
dc.TextOut(0,10,'Sample: 3174')
dc.TextOut(0,90,'Date:26/02/21')
dc.TextOut(0,180,'sample_name')
dc.EndPage()
dc.EndDoc()
```

This works well and prints to the label printer when it is defaulted, but in the future I will want to specify different printers for this. I've tried adding the name of the printer to the CreatePrinterDC line, but however I add it, it doesn't accept it. Is there any way to get a list of the printers available or some syntax for spesifying networked printers this way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wmi` module.

- `pip install wmi`

```
import wmi

c = wmi.WMI()
print(c.Win32_PrinterShare)
```

This will give you information about your connected Network Printers.
This is the microsoft C++ win32 docs, but since the **wmi** is a wrapper to all those classes, you can get valuable info anyway.

For example, you can `print(c.Win32_Printer.DeviceId)` and will return you the printer Id if at least one is connected, otherwise will return you None.

You should now read here the availiable method and classes that you can use: [win32 info](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-printer)